# Set background-image to change depending on the time

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to set my websites background image to change depending on what time it is.

This is the script I'm trying to use

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();
if (n > 20 || n < 6)
  ("backgrounds", "url('midnight.png')");
else if (n > 6 && n < 8)
  ("backgrounds", "url('sunrise.png')");
else if (n > 8 && n < 18)
  ("backgrounds", "url('noon.png')");
else (n > 18 && n < 20)
  ("backgrounds", "url('sunset.png')");
```

Im also having trouble figuring out het to set the `background-image` to use the above script to determine the background it should use

Comment: `("backgrounds", "url('midnight.png')")` as a JS expression doesn't make sense; it's just two string literals separated by a comma operator with the result being the 2nd one, which is discarded. Typically to set a background image with JS, you'd manipulate some element's `style` property, eg `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(midnight.png)";`

Comment: could you please show me a example of you using a js to change the background-image depending on the time

Comment: There's plenty of examples in the duplicate

Comment: whats the duplicate?

Comment: The link at the top of your post. You can keep using your current `if..else if..else` logic, just replace the `("background", "url(...)")` bits with the right code for assigning the `style.backgroundImage`

Comment: <script>
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getHours();
        if (n > 20 || n < 6)
            style.backgroundImage = "url(midnight.png)";
        else if (n > 6 && n < 8)
            style.backgroundImage = "url(sunrise.png)";
        else if (n > 8 && n < 18)
            style.backgroundImage = "url(noon.png)";
        else (n > 18 && n < 20)
            style.backgroundImage = "url(sunset.png)";
    </script> like this?

Comment: how make block things